# Updating Skills property of User through MS Graph API fails

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to update the "Skills" property of a user (note: NOT using the Me endpoint). This returns an exception. I'm using the .NET SDK `GraphServiceClient` to do so, using the latest 3.6.0 version.

**To Reproduce**

Steps to reproduce the behavior, use the following sample code:

```
var user = new User()
{
  Skills = skills
};
await graphClient.Users[userId].Request().UpdateAsync(user);
```

**Expected behavior**

I'd expect this code to send a POST request to the Graph API endpoint and that request should update the Skills property of the given used, provided that the authenticated service has been granted the `User.ReadWrite.All` permission in Azure AD (which it has).

Instead, the following error is being returned by the Graph endpoint:

```
  "error": {
    "code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException",
    "message": "A type named 'Microsoft.SharePoint.user' could not be resolved by the model. When a model is available, each type name must resolve to a valid type.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "1948a4ec-60fd-4212-873f-3d34f62f5601",
      "date": "2020-05-25T09:35:33"
    }
  }
}
```

Not sure why this would not work. I followed the samples although those do not specifically mention updating the `Skills` property, you'd expect that to work equally for all properties. When I omit the property from the updated `User` object, I do not get an error in return (but obviously there's nothing updated in that case).

Comment: Hi, if any of the posted answers resolves your question, please mark the answer by clicking the arrow and verify by clicking the emoji below. Doing so helps others find answers to their related questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Till it is fixed in v1 as mentioned by baywet you can also use the following as work around for your scenario.

Graph client by default adds odata.type as microsoft.graph.user and sharepoint doesn't expect that value. You could change the oDataType to "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity" or "Microsoft.SharePoint.user" or null, so that sharepoint can understand the type.

You can set the oDatatype by

```
var user = new User()
{
  Skills = skills
};
user.ODataType = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity";
await graphClient.Users[userId].Request().UpdateAsync(user);
```

Comment: Setting the types did not work. Switching to the beta endpoint worked a little, but not completely. See the comment I posted under @baywet's post

Answer (score 0):

This is an ongoing issue that is being addressed in the service. The beta version should already be fixed and the v1 is in progress.

As a workaround you can either use the beta version or craft the request manually without an odata type.

Comment: I tried switching to the beta endpoint, but that leaves me with a `DirectoryObjectUnauthorizedException` even though I believe to have the correct permissions assigned. Might relate to https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/296 which has not been answered in a long time unfortunately.